# Keeping entered values in a UI form after reloading the UI form

Tags: magento2.4

I have an own UI form in the backend to enter some stuff in an own database table. The responsible Save class checks after submit the form values if they are OK and if not redirects to the UI form with an error message. But in this case all entered values are gone. Is there a way to keep the entered values in the form after redirecting to it?
Please let me know.
Best regards,
Chequille

Comment: You are probably looking for the `DataPersistorInterface`.

Comment: hi, unfortunately I have no idea how this should work with UI forms. I think this could only work if I made my form not with UI but with an own block. WIth an UI form, I do not know where I can tell the UI form to load the stored post vars.